# Why was I suspended from reviewing for saying this answer is OK?

Tags: discussion, support, low-quality-posts, disputed-review-audits, spam

I was suspended from reviewing until February because I said this answer looked okay:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24199630

It appeared to give useful information as to why the user was having issues and I wasn't sure why it was incorrect to mark it as ok. Could anyone explain why this answer is spam?

Answer:

> [image]

Comment: I wonder if the answer-provider had a bunch of other spam answers, and then all their answers got nuked as spam, and this one somehow made it to the review queue?  Not a moderator, so it's a total wild guess, though.

Comment: Oh, look, yet another bad automated review.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables I wondered the same, apparently Enablex is also some form of oral medicine, but don't see how the answer relates to that

Comment: According to their profiles the OP and the answerer both work for the same company - so maybe some sort of voting ring?

Comment: @greg-449 Possible, but then I would assume that at least one account would be nuked, if not both.

Comment: What if Subrat is just a sockpuppet of Daljeet because the user didn't realize they could just Q&A their own questions?  In that case, I'd expect Subrat would be disabled/deleted, but Daljeet would be left alone.

Comment: @ConspicuousCompiler Yes, both accounts are usually merged in that situation.

Comment: [The OP's profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3751662/daljeet?tab=topactivity) shows a -102 rep change for this question (but nothing matches that in the reputation tab), so something suspicious must have happened with it. The timeline is a bit messy too. But anyway, that looks to me like a very bad choice for an audit.

Comment: It's definitely a bad audit and would have tricked most of the reviewers (including me).

Comment: Interesting.  The question's got some [interesting revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57821571/revisions).  It *should* be deleted.  Likely some revision purging and, I bet, user merging, going on.

Comment: This is rather strange. The [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57821571/timeline) shows the **question** being deleted as spam by one-shot mod vote (explains the -102). It looks like the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57841352/timeline) might have had its own spam flag raised by the moderator. What's downright bizarre is the moderator Ry- then *undeleted* the question, but left it with the Community lock. I think only Ry- can shed some light on what happened here

Comment: @Machavity Ry probably deleted it, then undeleted because he decided that a spam flag would be more appropriate. Not sure what happens with community lock when undeleting a spam answer. I don't think it matters much, that said. This platform complexity will never cease to surprise me....

Comment: I ask myself, if the team from stackoverflow think their bot is good enough to generate these audit questions why do they need us for reviewing?

Comment: Just got review banned because of something like this.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Not the moderator who handled this user as a whole but after examining poster profile it appears that all other posts by this user (7 total) are spam.

That particular one you failed the audit for hasn't any link and *looks* useful (plus it had +3/-1 votes *and accepted* when deleted).

I get the moderator point of view: the user posted spam on every other post, so this *has* to be spam. A global processing has been probably applied (but user wasn't removed)

It's clearly unfair to get an audit on that one so:

- I've unbanned you from reviews (we need help with the queues anyway :))
- I've undeleted/deleted the answer so it won't appear in low quality audits anymore (I could have left it undeleted but I respect the other moderator decision)

Pro-tip for future audits: when the audit system warns you about "possible spam" above the post, *always visit the real question to check*. Because 99% of the time the "possible spam" indication is real (it's intentional in order to be fair to reviewers).

Comment: Another pro-tip: Click on the score of the post to split upvotes and downvotes count. If the post is deleted, you'll get a prompt, otherwise the action would succeed. (I assumed that reviewer is already an established user)

Comment: @Kulfy this pro-tip is very good to see if it's an audit when the answer has actually -5 votes, but in that case it would fail I think: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24199630 post has +2 votes. And the fact it's deleted doesn't prevent to get the score (just tested, but maybe it's not the real audit conditions)

Comment: I can only split votes for posts which aren't deleted. May be because you're are a mod, you can split votes on deleted posts too. I'm not sure

Comment: that would be another privilege I didn't think I had :)